# Convert X25519 to Ed25519 in curve25519-dalek

Tags: rust, cryptography, elliptic-curve, ed25519, x25519

For a scenario in which only an X25519 keypair is available but I need to create and verify a signature with what I have, I am trying to convert an X25519 public key into an Ed25519 verification key that can successfully verify a signature made using the X25519 private key.

While generally frowned upon (I know the reasons, but as stated, the X25519 keypair is all I have), there is an implementation in the wild that does this, [available as C code](https://github.com/Syndace/libxeddsa/blob/main/src/pub_conversion.c). I am trying to follow this example.

As the surrounding software uses the [dalek](https://docs.rs/curve25519-dalek/latest/curve25519_dalek/) set of crates, I use this library to do the conversion as well. My conversion function for the public key reads:

```
pub(crate) fn x25519_pub_to_ed25519_ver(
    public_key: [u8; 32],
) -> Result<VerifyingKey, SignatureError> {
    match MontgomeryPoint(public_key).to_edwards(SIGN_BIT) {
        None => Err(SignatureError::new()),
        Some(key) => VerifyingKey::from_bytes(key.compress().as_bytes()),
    }
}
```

This calculates the Edwards point from the Montgomery point, and I have verified [the to_edwards code](https://docs.rs/curve25519-dalek/latest/src/curve25519_dalek/montgomery.rs.html#217-246) to do exactly what the reference code linekd above does.

For the signing party, I figured I need to make sure to use a private key that will yield the correct sign, as the transformation between X25519 and Ed25519 public keys is not 1:1. My reference library also has [an example how to produce a matching private key](https://github.com/Syndace/libxeddsa/blob/main/src/seed_priv_utils.c#L16), which I tried to immitate:

```
pub(crate) fn x25519_priv_to_ed25519_sig(private_key: &StaticSecret) -> SigningKey {
    let clamped = clamp_integer(private_key.to_bytes());
    let signing_key = SigningKey::from_bytes(&clamped);
    let test_public_key = signing_key.verifying_key().to_bytes();

    if (test_public_key[31] & 0x80) >> 7 == SIGN_BIT {
        signing_key
    } else {
        let scalar = Scalar::from_bytes_mod_order(clamped);
        let neg = scalar.invert();
        SigningKey::from_bytes(&neg.to_bytes())
    }
}
```

My test code, sadly, does not work, the public key generated does not match the Ed25519 verification key derived directly from the calculated Ed25519 secret key:

```
const TEST_MESSAGE: &[u8] = b"Das Pferd frisst keinen Gurkensalat.";

fn main() {
    let private_key = StaticSecret::random();
    println!("X25519 private key: {:02x?}", private_key.to_bytes());
    let public_key = PublicKey::from(&private_key);

    let signing_key = x25519_priv_to_ed25519_sig(&private_key);
    println!("Ed25519 signing key: {:02x?}", signing_key.to_bytes());
    let signature = signing_key.sign(TEST_MESSAGE);

    let verifying_key = x25519_pub_to_ed25519_ver(public_key.to_bytes()).unwrap();
    println!(
        "Transformed verifying key: {:02x?}",
        verifying_key.to_bytes()
    );
    println!(
        "Real verifying key: {:02x?}",
        signing_key.verifying_key().to_bytes()
    );
    let result = verifying_key.verify(TEST_MESSAGE, &signature);
    assert!(result.is_ok());
}
```

At which point am I doing the conversion wrong?

A minimal working example, ready to be run with `cargo`, can be [found on Codeberg](https://codeberg.org/Natureshadow/rust-25519-mwe).

Comment: A secret X25519 key is a random 32 bytes byte sequence. If you have used this byte sequence for the Ed25519 secret key to generate the signature (and this is how *a signature made using the X25519 private key* sounds), the Ed25519 public key for verification is simply generated from the Ed25519 secret key according to the *regular* Ed25519 key generation.

Comment: @Topaco Correct. And now, I need to recreate this verifying key by deriving it from the X25519 public key instead. That's what the question is about. As you can see in the MWE, the goal is to get the verification key derived directly from the Ed25519 secret key to be equivalent to that derived from the X25519 public key.

Comment: It seems to me that the problem with this question is not the implementation itself, but the math behind it, so perhaps these aspects of the question are more appropriate for [*cryptography*](https://crypto.stackexchange.com). I suspect that the assumption of deriving the public Ed25519 key (for verification) from the public X25519 key (via birational mapping) may not be correct (as well as the logic for deriving the secret Ed25519 key from the secret X25519 key).

Comment: @Topaco The assumption, as well as the referecne implementation linked above, are one of the core principles of the Signal messenger. I have become a witness of Signal working quite well, so I am convinced that its cryptographic assumptions are valid ;). Hence, this question is specifically about porting the algorithm to Rust using the dalek crates.

Comment: For future readers who, like me, are wondering how an X25519 key pair could be converted into an Ed25519 key pair: This is about [XEdDSA](https://signal.org/docs/specifications/xeddsa/#xeddsa). Possibly the dalek library is not suitable for this (but only for the standard X25519 and Ed25519).

Comment: @Topaco Ah, I just saw your new comment after answeing myself. If you want to post your comment as an answer, I will accept it instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `verifying_key()` as generated by `ed25519_dalek` is not directly the point derived from the scalar by multiplication on the curve. That's because the secret key used for signing in real Ed25519 is not the scalar itself, but the result of a SHA-512 key derivation over the scret scalar, yielding 32 bytes as the new scalar and 32 bytes as pseudo-random hash input for the signature.

In order for independent key derivation for the signing and verifying part to work, a different key derivation algorithm is necessary, as laid out by Signal's [XEdDSA](https://www.signal.org/docs/specifications/xeddsa/) specification.

Comment: FWIW, here's my implementation: https://crates.io/crates/xeddsa